# My main interest: singlular vs plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm not sure if I should say: "computers are my main interest" or "computers is my main interest". "Computers" is plural while "interest" is singular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as it says on the tin, "computers are" because they are plural.

It's true that "computers" is plural while "interest" is singular but that does not cause a conflict. What specifically is the subject of the sentence?

If the sentence is "Computers are my main interest" then computers are the subject.

If the sentence is "My main interest is computers” then the interest is the subject.

(That assumes that the interest is concrete “computers” individually, what they have in common and the differences among them, rather than the abstract activity, “computing”…)